# django model forms, display text for a foreign key (not using __str__ in model)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a mapping table which I am referencing as a foreign key for another table, i.e.

mapping table:

```
class DeviceCircuitSubnets(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    circuit = models.ForeignKey(Circuit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

then in my interface table:

```
class InterfaceData(models.Model):
    device_circuit = models.ForeignKey(DeviceCircuit, verbose_name="Device", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    interface_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Interface name')
    dashboard = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Display on monitoring dashboard?")
    wallboard = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Display on wallboards?")
```

Im building a form for interface data in forms.py but the display text of the drop down is just DeviceCircuit Object. I know this is because I haven't set def **str**(self), but it is my understanding that I would be making uncessecary calls to other models if I did this (i.e. the str would reference device.hostname and circuit.circuit_type.circuit_type and so on which I dont want.

I would just like to change the display for drop downs as and when I need them.

so far I have filtered and renamed the field but cannot seem to set the display, is this possible using a model form?

```
class InterfaceDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InterfaceData
        fields = ['device_circuit','interface_name','dashboard','wallboard']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_add = kwargs.pop("is_add", False)
        device_id = kwargs.pop("device_id")
        super(InterfaceDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['device_circuit'].queryset = DeviceCircuit.objects.filter(device_id=device_id) \
                                                                                        .select_related('device') \
                                                                                        .select_related('circuit') \
                                                                                        .select_related('circuit__circuit_type') \
                                                                                        .select_related('circuit__service_contact') \
                                                                                        .select_related('circuit__service_contact__provider') 
        self.fields['device_circuit'].label = 'Device / Circuit'
```

Comment: What text do want to appear in the dropdown?

Comment: it would be '{} - {} {}'.format(device.hostname,circuit.circuit_type, circuit.provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the dropdown text to be  `'{} - {} {}'.format(device.hostname,circuit.circuit_type, circuit.provider)` then you are correct, that will make calls to other models. But is that really a problem? You'll have to do it at some point if you want that information displayed. Assuming you use select/prefetch_related whenever you are calling **str** for DeviceCircuit it should be efficient. When is 'DeviceCircuit Object' ever going to be usefull anyways.

If you still would rather not override **str** then you could subclass ModelChoiceField as outlined in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

```
class DeviceCircuitField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, device_circuit):
        circuit = device_circuit.circuit
        device = device_circuit.device
        return '{} - {} {}'.format(
            device.hostname, circuit.circuit_type, circuit.service_contact.provider
        )


class InterfaceDataForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InterfaceData
        fields = ['device_circuit','interface_name','dashboard','wallboard']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_add = kwargs.pop("is_add", False)
        device_id = kwargs.pop("device_id")
        super(InterfaceDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['device_circuit'] = DeviceCircuitField(
            queryset=DeviceCircuit.objects.filter(device_id=device_id).select_related(
                'device', 'circuit', 'circuit__circuit_type', 'circuit__service_contact__provider'
            ),
            label='Device / Circuit'
        )
```